# Calculating the probability that a bivariate normal variable falls into a given region of the plane

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a bivariate normal distribution, where $X$ has mean $\mu_X$, $Y$ has mean $\mu_Y$, and the covariance matrix is the identity matrix. I also have a set of points, $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ with coordinates $((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...,(x_n,y_n))$.

I'm splitting the plane into regions based on the nearest point using the standard Cartesian distance (if it makes life easier I'm open to using a different norm such as $L_1$, but ideally I don't want to do this). These regions are $R_1,R_2,...,R_n$. My question is that if $\boldsymbol{Z}=(X,Y)$, how can I find $P(Z\in{R_i})$, ideally with a method other than simulation? With one variable the problem is extremely easy but I'd like to try and expand this to a bivariate normal, or even beyond if possible.

Comment: This [paper](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jcmsi/10/2/10_110/_pdf) may help but is not particularly easy to read..! And I am afraid there is no generic close-form solution to the question.

Comment: @Xi'an That paper is a good solution. Despite the apparently dense mathematics, it is simple and elementary: a direct application of Green's Theorem gives Proposition 1, which is a straightforward recipe for integrating *any* bivariate Normal density over *any* closed polygon. (It is readily generalized to infinite polygons.) Because the Voronoi cells in the present question are typically found by means of a triangulation algorithm, the problem reduces to triangles. An efficient algorithm will avoid computing the contribution of each edge twice (it bounds two cells).